# run cronjob only once on time defined by timestamps

Tags: php, timestamp, cron

I would like to execute a PHP-script automatically on a timestamp defined time.
So lets say I have calculated a future-timestamp (e.g. 1359504000) in another PHP-script and exactly at this time (something like) a cronjob should  call the other script. afterwards it (I am thinking about conjob currently) should be disabled/killed/deleted. 
What would be the best way to do this type of task?
thanks!

Comment: Cron is for recurring tasks. You can use the Linux command `at` to schedule a one-off task.

Comment: If its a system you want to scale up, you may be able to do this with a message queue. Some message queue systems may already support delays, or a delay can be built into the message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this process multiple times, and you don't need strict timing, you can create a cronjob that goes every 30/10/5/1 minutes (depending on your thoughts) which looks for the timestamps and calls the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there isn't a way to do that.

At the most you can run automatically the cronjob every minute and check if you have to do some function. This because the cronjob is for recuring tasks only